# Extending JFrame - how does "super" keyword work?

Tags: java, object, jframe, super

I've made a class that extends `JFrame`, and in my classes constructor, to set the title I can either use:

```
super("title");
setTitle("title");
```

or just create a `JFrame` object i.e:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("title);
```

How does the compiler differentiate from all of these to conclude the same thing? I know super is used to call overridden methods in the superclass, but how does it specifically know to call the `setTitle` method?

My idea is that super calls the constructor of `JFrame` class, and there is only one constructor which takes a string parameter, so it's basically doing:
`JFrame f = new JFrame("title);`, without explicitly creating the object.

Is this true? If not, can someone explain what super is exactly doing, and why `setTitle` does not need an object reference?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `new JFrame( "title" )` calls `JFrame`'s constructor.  It may call `setTitle()` (but it probably doesn't), or it may just set the internal variable used to hold the title.
2. `super.setTitle()` is just a method call.  If you have overridden `setTitle()`, it'll ignore your definition and call the same method on the super class.  It's normally used for "chaining" to a super class's methods.
3. `super( "title" )` can only be called as the first line of a constructor.  It is not a method call.  It calls a specific constructor in the super class, constructs that object, then continues with your constructor code.  This is the way all constructors work.  If you don't specify a constructor, the no-argument constructor (`super()`) is called automatically.

Comment: Most detailed answer which has helped me alot. I didn't know super() was specifically for constructor calls, but it makes sense now that super() = constructor calls and super.methodName() calls the overriden method in the superclass. Thanks alot for this

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Frame Object, calling super (JFrame) means that you are passing the parameter into JFrame so `JFrame jf = new JFrame("Title");` is the same as `super("Title");` (assuming super type is JFrame)

Comment: Thanks for that. You mentioned "If you look at the Frame Object", where can I see this? Sorry if this is a stupid question. Also what do you mean by "assuming super type in JFrame"?

Comment: Assuming the super type is JFrame means that the class in question `implements` JFrame.

If you type JFrame jf = new JFrame(); into something like eclipse and on mac command+click the word JFrame (on Window control+click [NOT right click]) it will bring you to where JFrame is actually declared in java.

Comment: I'll put a screen shot in a minute

Comment: http://gyazo.com/82d77b6b6fb2a534439ece4b74fad19e - thats what I get when i control + click. I believe I tried this before with the same error

Comment: do you have idk/jre and are you using netbeans or eclipse

Comment: I have JDK/JRE and I am using eclipse. I fixed the problem - I needed to import a src.zip file which wasn't done for me for some reason. My JUnit doesn't seem to work now though :(

Comment: post a question about that and comment a link.

Comment: It's not too much of a concern to me right now as JUnit tests do still seem to be working. Strange..

Answer (score 1):

When you call `super("title")` in your super class, you tell Java "to instantiate my object, first call the constructor on the super class that takes a String argument". If you don't have an explicit super call, then the no-arg constructor is called (as is always the case with the `Object()` constructor). It turns out that that JFrame constructor calls `setTitle` with its argument.

When you call `setTitle("title")`, this is implied, so you call the method on your object. If you haven't overridden it, then the super class implementation is called.

Answer (score 0):

> how does it specifically know to call the setTitle method?

Calling `super()` by itself will call a superclass constructor.

When you call `setTitle()` java looks to see if that method exists in the current class. If it doesn't, it will look at the parent class.

If you've overridden `setTitle()`, calling `setTitle()` from within the child class will call that class' method. If you call `super.setTitle()` it will call the `setTitle()` method in the super class.

Comment: "Calling super() by itself will call a superclass constructor." Something I didn't know, I thought it was related to methods aswell. Thanks alot for this.